# learning swift trying to understand how to make code simplier

Tags: swift

is it possible to make this void code simplier

it basicly grab 2 values from 2 box and depending on the selected
operator make the calculation.

```
   @IBAction func enterpressedinbox2(sender: AnyObject) {
    let value1toint = Int(value1.stringValue)
    let value2toint = Int(value2.stringValue)
    var result = 0;

    if operatorselection.stringValue == "+"{
        result = value1toint! + value2toint!
    }
    if operatorselection.stringValue == "-"{
        result = value1toint! - value2toint!
    }
    if operatorselection.stringValue == "*"{
        result = value1toint! * value2toint!
    }
    if operatorselection.stringValue == "/"{
        result = value1toint! / value2toint!
    }
    let resultinttostring = String(result)

    resultlabel.stringValue = ": " + resultinttostring
    view.window!.title = "The result is " + resultinttostring
}
```

Comment: "void code"? What does that mean? Do you mean "function"?

Comment: what about a switch? :)

Comment: functions are first class so you can store them, i.e. in an array or dictionary and index the one you want with the text in the selection, or better an enum identifier assigned to the selectable item

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, with a dictionary of functions:

```
@IBAction func enterpressedinbox2(sender: AnyObject) {
    let ops : [String: (Int, Int)->Int] = [ "+" : { x, y in x + y }, 
                                            "-" : { x, y in x - y },
                                            "*" : { x, y in x * y }, 
                                            "/" : { x, y in x / y } ]
    if let x = Int(value1.stringValue),
       let y = Int(value2.stringValue),
       let f = ops[operatorselection.stringValue] {
           let result = String(f(x, y))
           resultlabel.stringValue = ": " + result
           view.window!.title = "The result is " + result
    }
}
```